# Associate a usage plan to api key using boto3 AWS api gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-api-gateway

Hey I am using boto3 library to create a new api key. I successfully created a new api key but I am having trouble associate it with the existing usage plan. Can you please help me to associate api-key to existing usage plan
My code to create api key

```
import boto3
apiclient= boto3.client('apigateway')
response= apiclient.create_api_key(
        name='string',
        enabled=True,
        stageKeys=[{
            'restApiId':'string',
            'stageName':'string'
        }]
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was to able to attach usage plan to api key with `create_usage_plan_key()` method
Implementation:

```
import boto3
apiclient= boto3.client('apigateway')
response= apiclient.create_api_key(
        name='string',
        enabled=True,
        stageKeys=[{
            'restApiId':'string',
            'stageName':'string'
        }]
        )
api_key_id=response['id']
usage_planId="<Your usage plan id>"
keytype='API_KEY' 

usageresponse= apiclient.create_usage_plan_key(
     usagePlanId= usage_planId,
     keyId=api_key_id,
     keyType=keytype
     )
```

For more information, go to this documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_usage_plan_key